# Spoken English and casual writing

Tags: meaning, writing, academic-writing

1: "When someone tries to win a war before it starts innocent people die everytime"

2: "He takes Watson wicket, scoring 100, 3 sixes and 7 fours"

Be aware first one taken a movie called Avengers: age of Ultron, and second one from a cricket match report

I don't have problem understanding them

Can anyone convert them into formal written language?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those sentences are exclusively casual or informal.  They could be used in formal contexts as well as casual ones.

(The first one is missing a comma before "innocent", but that's not a casual/formal thing, that's just correct grammar in general)

The second sentence is highly technical, using a number of terms that only make sense within the context of cricket, but that does not make it informal, just specialized.